# What do the numbers on motors mean (How do I read them?)

Tags: motor

I salvaged from an old microwave, the motor that spins the food tray. I'm trying to figure out how much voltage I need to apply to it in order to get it to spin, but I cant make any sense out of the numbers on it. It's a Synchronous Motor.

This is what's on it:

100/120v~  50/60Hz  4W
4/4.8r/min  CW/CCW

I can guess that it rotates from 4 to 4.8 rotations per minute? but other than that, I'm clueless. What do these other things mean? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Taking a few guesses here, but:

100-120V~: operating voltage, "~" (tilde) indicates AC voltage

50-60Hz: operating AC frequency

4W: power consumption (maximum stall perhaps?)

CW/CCW: works in both ways (clockwise and counterclockwise.) This usually means it is a synchronous motor, and its direction depends on either the sign of the incoming AC waveform, or whichever direction has the least torque - in other words, it's more or less random.

Comment: It's synchronous to the power frequency.  So 4 revs per minute at 50 Hz power and 4.8 at 60 Hz.

Comment: 100-120 is what you will get out of a wall outlet in the USA. 60Hz is what you will get in the USA also.

Comment: Does this mean that I will need 100-120 volts in order to get it to spin?

Comment: @walt, dependent on where you live, you get this from a wall socket. In the USA you get 110+-10 from a wall socket. This is why it is spec'ed 100 to 120.

Comment: @Walt - Yes. Also, it HAS to be AC.

Comment: Yikes! I never though such a small motor would need that much juice in order to work. Makes me a bit squeamish on using it for simple hobby electronic projects.

Comment: @Walk, they Intentionally use a motor that works directly off of AC so that there are no electronics required to step down voltage.

Comment: @Walt - High voltage **does not** mean lots of juice, it just means high voltage. Power (or juice, if you will), is voltage * current.

Comment: @Kortuk That's not correct, AC is used in motors so it can create a changing magnetic field without any commutator. This changing field is what spins the rotor. The voltage is usually used as is, without stepping it down.

Comment: @Austin - "No electronics required to step down voltage" - I meant to be saying, you dont have to step down voltage by design. Sorry if my comment is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

CW/CCW - Clockwise & Counterclockwise. a lot of turntable motors for microwaves will alternate the spin direction to help even out cooking, each time it is powered up the spin will reverse from the previous time...

1st time, let say clockwise
2nd time, then counterclockwise
3rd time, clockwise again...